# Rails 3.0.10, customer routes, post and form_for tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, form-for, custom-routes

I have this in my routes:

```
resources :events do
  collection do
    post 'moderate'
  end
end
```

Rake routes tells me:

```
moderate_events POST /events/moderate(.:format) {:controller=>"events", :action=>"moderate"}
```

I have an "administration" controller that simply lists Events that need moderating:

```
@modevents = Event.where('moderated <> 1')
```

So far so good, all the events that haven't been moderated can be displayed in the view:

```
<%- @modevents.each do |me| -%>
  Display Stuff here
<%- end -%>
```

I want to put a form in the loop that updated the moderated value but for the life of me I can't work out what to put in the form_for - I have tried:

```
<%= form_for me, :url => moderate_events_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The html returned is:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/events/moderate" class="edit_event" id="edit_event_1" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
```

When I click the "Submit" button I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find Event with ID=moderate
```

The solution is very simple, in routes change "post" to "put":

```
resources :events do
  collection do
    put 'moderate'
  end
end
```

And now it works as it should. Updates, even custom ones are "put" functions.

Comment: There was when I started typing it up but I worked it out while I was writing it up. So I thought I would leave it here for the benefit of others. And by the looks of it someone else has already found it useful.

Comment: Put the last three sections in a comment, and then it's a Q/A format... but no need to close, it is a useful question

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually in the text above at the bottom but perhaps not obvious. If you are updating stuff you should be using "put" not post.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use POST by specifying:

```
<%= form_for me, :url => moderate_events_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
```

but as said before, the distinction needs to be made between updating and creating. The standard in rails is update==put, and create==post.