# No Route Matches in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, change-password

In my ruby on rails project, I am using devise as the authentication plugin. Now I have added the change password functionality to the project and when submit the form, I'm getting an error `No route matches "/users/update_password"`

This is my update password code

```
  def update_password
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      # Sign in the user by passing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
```

This is my route details

```
resources :users, :only => [] do
        collection do
            get 'current'
            get 'edit'
            post 'update_password'
        end
    end
```

and this is my edit form

```
<div id="loginForm">
    <div id="loginHeader"><h3>Change Password</h3></div>
    <div id="loginContent">
        <%= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "update_password" }) do |f| %>
            <p><%= f.password_field :current_password, :class => "login_txt", :placeholder => "We need your current password to confirm your changes", :autocomplete => "off" %></p>
            <p><%= f.password_field :password, :class => "login_txt", :placeholder => "New password", :autocomplete => "off"  %></p>
            <p><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => "login_txt", :placeholder => "Confirm password", :autocomplete => "off" %></p>
            <p>
                <input id="user_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Update Password" class="login_btn" /> 
            </p>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me how to fix this issue

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you run `rake routes` and paste the output related to Devise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `routes.rb` you define `update_password` as a POST action on the collection (`/users/update_password`), but in your form you are implicitly defining it as a PUT action when you pass `@user` to `form_for`, since `@user` already exists.

I haven't tested this, but I believe that changing your route on the collection from a POST to a PUT should fix this:

```
resources :users, :only => [] do
  collection do
    get 'current'
    get 'edit'
    put 'update_password'
  end
end
```

See also: [Rails 3.0.10, customer routes, post and form_for tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303752/rails-3-0-10-customer-routes-post-and-form-for-tag)

Comment: Thanks a lot, now the mentioned error was fixed, but the password is not updated

Comment: I don't use devise myself so I don't know exactly how it works, but maybe the problem is that the `password` attribute is protected? If that is the case, you need to either add `attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation` in the User model or alternatively you can set the attributes in the controller code explicitly.

Comment: also, try changing `update_attributes` to `update_attributes!` and see what error it returns.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day. When I run `update_attributes!` it gave me the error. Its about validation issue. Now its fixed. Thanks a lot :)